# Dynamically indent UITextView's first line

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView in a prototype UITableView cell. I'd like to dynamically indent the first line of the UITextView to make room for a button that will have a variable width depending on the cell row. The button will vary in width because it's title will contain usernames in an activity feed.

Think of Instagram or any app that has a feed with clickable usernames on the left and text directly following.

I've been able to get close by counting the number of characters in the button title and left padding the text of my UITextView with a series of @" " blank spaces. This is akin to what other SO posts have suggested.

This is inaccurate for me because the width of blank spaces don't precisely match that of the button title because different characters have different widths.

Does anyone know if it is possible to indent a UITextView by a specific float value? I've been able to convert the width of the button title to a float and I believe that this would solve my issue.